# Is this matrix singular and if yes, why?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, covariance

Consider the following matrix
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} p_1(1-p_1) & -p_1p_2 & \cdots & -p_1p_k \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ -p_kp_1 & -p_kp_2 & \cdots & -p_k(1-p_k) \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
with $\sum_{i=1}^k p_i = 1$. Is this matrix singular?
I think it is, and I'm sure that it is for $k=1,2$ and also for simple cases if $k=3$. At deciding whether a matrix is invertible or not, the only theorem I remember is that only singular matrices have determinant zero. Unfortunately the diagonal entries make it not so easy to write this matrix in another way thereby not changing the determinant.

Is there anybody with an idea? I thank in advance, because I can't do that in the comments and of course because I'm grateful.

Comment: What's $n$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Multiply it by the vector $(1,1,...,1)^T$.

Comment: I have to suspect either the $n$ in the last row was put there by mistake or else it should have been in the first row as well.

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake

Comment: @EEE I did, but this turns out not to be an eigenvector

Comment: The product of that matrix by the vector $(1,1,...,1)^T$ is a vector that has entries $p_i(1-p_1-p_2-...-p_k)=0$. So, it is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: @EEE Oh ok, then my calculation was incorrect. Ok, eigenvalues and eigenvectors make me think of diagonalizable matrices. But yet the matrix itself need not have an inverse.

Comment: Oh ok, it can't have eigenvalue 0 if it would be a non-singular matrix